# no-use-before-define typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have 2 typescript interfaces that have a member that is of the type of the other interface (circular reference). My linter complains that I cannot use an interface before I defined it. However, I have to define one first.

```js
interface Foo {
  // error, Bar was used before it was defined
  bar: Bar
}

interface Bar {
  foo: Foo
}
```

I am very much aware that I can just disable the linter rule for the line but what is the proper way of solving it?

Comment: The linter is wrong. You haven't even specified which linter it is or rules you're using, but the point is that you need to suppress this rule. It's nonsense.

Comment: The rule is no-use-before-define and its from typescript eslint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With eslint and typescript, there are 2 rules to consider

- [no-use-before-define](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-use-before-define)
- [@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-use-before-define/)

In the docs [how to use](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-use-before-define/#how-to-use), it is explained that you must turn off `no-use-before-define` and enable `@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define`.

This made the error go away for me.

```
// eslint.js

module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    // Note: you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming file extension to `d.ts`.

I met the same problem and solved it after referring to [this reply](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2519#issuecomment-688633630).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).